# How to fix ruby on rails on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Everything was working just fine then I installed devise gem to make the login and the email confirmation functions, it worked fine after that I generated a controller with an "index" action. Then I tried to visit http://localhost:3000/welcome/index then I got this error:

```
Started GET "/welcome/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-06-01 16:56:34 +0200
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 84)

Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
```

I also get the same error when I create new projects. 
I have tried to delete ruby from the system and reinstall it also didn't help

I am using ruby version : ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]
rails version : Rails 6.0.3.1
und rubyMine

Does anyone habe an idea what is going wrong ?
Any help would be appreciated

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile and the command you're using to start the rails server?

Comment: Well the error code is heap stack corruption according to Microsoft questions. The only reference I can find to this code in regards to its interaction with ruby is some [failed tests](http://mswinci.japaneast.cloudapp.azure.com/vc12-x64/ruby-master/log/20170726T053944Z.fail.html.gz) revolving around [`TestOpenURISSL#test_proxy_cacert_dir`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/test/open-uri/test_ssl.rb#L159). Seems like this issue is going to be difficult to solve.

Comment: As an aside Windows 10 supports [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) which makes ruby development much more natural in a windows environment by running ruby in a Linux subsystem

Comment: @scilence you can now see the Gemfiel
and I run the application with the run button in rubyMine 
I have also tried to create and run a project from the cmd terminal and ot the same results

Comment: @engineersmnky I have been trying to use WSL with rubyMine but for some reason it is not working!